# Trouble with Ubuntu on Oracle VM

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running Ubuntu on an Oracle VirtualBox virtual machine. I clicked the "install Ubuntu" button, and it took me through a wizard. I am currently on the following step:

[image: ubuntu 'who are you' page]

Unfortunately, the "forward" button is disabled. What's up with this?  I tried entering different data for the form on this step, going back and redoing part of the wizard, and rebooting the machine. Nothing worked.

My host OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this software, but note that there's no green tick after the username field and that Unix usernames are traditionally lower-case.

Comment: Nice catch @Phil